# ORA-00905: missing keyword - Alter table modify column not working in Oracle 10g

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, alter-table

I regularly take caution when creating tables for database. This time I came across a situation to alter a table.

I wanted to change the Data Type of a field/column in Table.

To change the data type of a column in a table: General Syntax

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype
```

SQL Query :

```
alter table employee modify column ename varchar(40);
```

I Rarely use Alter and Modify commands. This time when tried, it throws me an Error as `ORA-00905: missing keyword`.

I surfed the Internet and referred StackOverflow raised questions, but there is no relative answer found.

I also referred this Oracle Documentation : 
[Oracle Reference Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_3001.htm#SQLRF01001)

But It did not help.

Comment: Just like you do in your mysql query, use alter table modify, not alter table alter. Also do not use COLUMN in your query.

Comment: Its "alter table table-name" which i tried " Employee " is a table name

Comment: `alter table employee modify ename varchar(40);`  remove the column keyword

Comment: Thank you  @Mihai, its a simple mistake I wrongly understood the syntax. Its all fine.

Comment: Search for `Modifying Table Columns: Examples` on the docs you linked.  An example is there for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name datatype
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
ALTER TABLE Shopper MODIFY  MobileNo(varchar2(15))